# Scheduling Tasks in GoDaddy windows shared hosting

Tags: asp.net, .net, windows, scheduled-tasks, hosting

I am trying to create a scheduled task in GoDaddy windows shared hosting account. I have some logic in my .Net C# class project where I have to call a function on daily basis. I have tried by converting it to an executable(.exe) and configured in godaddy as per

https://in.godaddy.com/help/scheduling-tasks-with-plesk-shared-hosting-8970

But that doesn't work for an .exe.

Eventually I have tried calling that function from an aspx by referencing the class project in the WebApp (because that's what the URL suggests). Now I am blocked with some error which says Exception calling "DownloadString" with "1" argument(s): "URI formats are not supported."

Looks like I am doing something wrong while configuring my aspx.

These are my configuration details:

Path to an executable file:

> C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe

Arguments:

> -c "(new-object system.net.webclient).downloadstring('http://DOMAIN_NAME.in\SOME_FOLDER\Default.aspx')"

Called up GoDaddy folks to provide a sample, But they said they do not any sample for the same (very irritating).

Can Someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue with my configuration, in fact I have just managed to make it work, here it is:

### **ASPX Deployment:**

Path to an executable file:

C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe

Arguments:

-c "(new-object system.net.webclient).downloadstring('http://YOUR_DOMAIN.in/Default.aspx')"

**Note**: Default.aspx must be placed in httpdocs folder (This is the default folder where you place your website related files).

### **PHP Deployment:**

Path to an executable file:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP54\php-cgi.exe

Arguments:

G:\PleskVhosts\readefy.in\httpdocs\YOUR_SCHEDULED_TASK.php

**NOTE**: Looks like only these 2 options are available for scheduling your tasks via windows shared hosting.

Answer (score 1):

Godaddy already removed task scheduler and they no longer support it since  March 2018.

Comment: Refer : https://in.godaddy.com/help/which-components-does-my-hosting-support-5614
.
It states :
' Note: Scheduled Tasks no longer supported as of 2/2018. '

Comment: Is there any alternative ?

Comment: Some web api check your site every minute, You can use them to start page that do some function 
https://superuser.com/questions/19126/

Answer (score 0):

you can create a API and call it by

> Executable : C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
>
> Argument :  Invoke-RestMethod 'mysite.com/API/MethodName"

The [Invoke-RestMethod](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/Invoke-RestMethod) cmdlet sends HTTP and HTTPS requests to Representational State Transfer (REST) web services that returns richly structured data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I didn't get to try this but hope it works.